# Problem unpacking field with jPOS for ISO8583

Tags: jpos

Newbie to `jPOS` and `ISO`. Tried parsing an `ISO8583-1987` message with the `jPOS` library and got the below error. Please suggest how could it be debugged for more information.

```java
    var isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
    isoMsg.setPackager(new ISO87APackagerBBitmap());
    isoMsg.unpack(payload);
```

```
Caused by: org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 54 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 797 too long. Max: 120) unpacking field=54, consumed=140
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:341)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:479)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a logger and a log listener to the packager:

```java
Logger logger = new Logger();
logger.addListener(new SimpleLogListener());
ISOBasePackager packager = new ISO87APackagerBBitmap();
packager.setLogger(logger, "packager");
isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
isoMsg.unpack(payload);
```

There you will be able to see from which field the packager is unaligned. But since probably the packager will not suit your needs, I would use a `GenericPackager` and start modifying the fields that are not aligned. It's also important to check that every filed in your packager aligns with the spec of that payload.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple JBang script as a starter.

https://gist.github.com/ar/e5459490510e5d4547e4e3b6880c06cb

As a matter of fact, if you have JBang installed, you can just try this online with the following commmand:

```
jbang https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ar/e5459490510e5d4547e4e3b6880c06cb/raw/2a64f4066be821c57e10cfac0038a5f3332aaa77/PackagerDebug.java
```

You need to of course use your payload, and packager configuration.

Comment: Thank you, shall try it.